# PostgreSQL: Table has type character varying, but query expects timestamp without time zone

Tags: postgresql, copy, partitioning

In a PostgreSQL database, when I tried to make use of COPY function to insert a timestamp value into a table that partitoined with that timestamp field, I got blelow error message:

```
ERROR:  attribute 11 has wrong type
DETAIL:  Table has type character varying, but query expects timestamp without time zone.
```

I COPY the same timestamp vaue to anther table that has no partitioning and result is good. Therefor I guess this might be a problem for **pg_pathman**

```
DATA=# copy table_without_partition(created_time) from '/tmp/test.csv' with csv;
COPY 1
```

Below is may testing env and data:

Database: postgres 9.6.2

Partition with pg_pathman:

```
select create_range_partitions('table'::regclass,'created_time','2017-02-08 00:00:00'::timestamp,interval '1 hour',96,false );
```

The csv content I test for COPY function: `2017-02-08 00:00:00`

The command I test:

```
 copy table(created_time) from '/tmp/test.csv' with csv;
```

Would someone give me some advise and help me out?

Comment: Problem resolved! For more details, please refer to https://github.com/postgrespro/pg_pathman/issues/87#ref-commit-9a354ad